# GCC -Wconversion warning for 16-bit addition

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion, gcc-warning

What would be the proper way to resolve warnings of this kind in the existing codebase?

```
void test(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    // warning: conversion to 'uint16_t' from 'int' may alter its value
    uint16_t value = (x + 1) * y;
    ...
}
```

All three values are unsigned 16-bit integers and any arithmetical overflows would be performed correctly without warnings it this platform's `int` was 16-bit, and I don't see another way this piece of code should be written, apart from casting the result due to integer promotion.

1. Should I cast in all such cases? Casting feels like I am doing something wrong.
2. Disabling the warning? I would prefer not to disable the warning completely, as it might be useful in some cases.

Comment: Yeah, but `int` is probably 32 bits or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I cast in all such cases? Casting feels like I am doing something wrong.

It's the correct thing to do here, at least if the code should be portable. If it's only ever compiled for 16bit platforms, there shouldn't be a warning, otherwise, silence the warning with an explicit cast to `uint16_t`:

```
uint16_t value = (uint16_t) (x + 1) * y;
```

There's nothing better you can do: all arithmetic operations are carried out as (at least) `int` and the compiler reminds you of it. Depending on the values of `x` and `y`, it's quite possible the result doesn't fit in an `uint16_t`. Explicitly writing the cast documents you're aware of that and either want the truncation or assure it won't happen.

Answer (score 3):

***Note: the following is only true in the 16-bit int case***

warning: was about implicit conversion of `x` to `int` because `1` is of type `int`.
Later conversion of `y` to `int` for same reason would also trigger this.

Simply mark the `1` as unsigned

```
void test(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    uint16_t value = (x + 1u) * y;
    ...
}
```

No casting required.

This will also work in *16 bit case*:

```
void test(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    uint16_t value = x * y + y;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This would only make sense with 16bit `int`, and the question doesn't read like this was assumed/guaranteed. Not my DV though ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen OP said platform's int was 16 bit

Comment: "*would be performed correctly without warnings it this platform's int was 16-bit*" sounds subjunctive to me. Plus good compilers typically have explicit warnings about signed/unsigned conversions.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, not my first language :), had to google subjunctive

Comment: You can never be sure, that's why I think your answer should explicitly state it's **only** about the special case of a 16bit platform :) (in all other cases, casting **is** required to avoid the typical warnings)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, @Felix is right, my platform is 32-bit, I was just trying to say that integer promotion happens here even if it doesn't bring any benefits. But both snippets will still cause warnings on 32-bit gcc.

Comment: @Lou "*even if it doesn't bring any benefits.*" <- how can you know? 32bits are probably the "natural word size" of the machine, and with 32 bit registers, arithmetic operations might be fastest when carried out as 32 bits.

Comment: @Lou happy to help refine the question then :)

Comment: @GuntherSchulz the second (in your edit) won't do any good with 32bit `int`. Any arithmetic operation triggers the promotion to `int`.

Comment: I meant in the 16 bit case. You got a UV from me, you absolutely right! Edited mine to remove confusion

Comment: @Felix: well I am aware of the performance benefits, what I wanted to say is that (unless I am wrong) the integer-promoted version can have UB if both values are 0xFFFF due to signed integer overflow, while the 16-bit platform version would be fine.

Comment: @Lou when promoting, *unsigned* int is chosen if the value can't be represented as a signed int. **edit**: did you mean `INT_MAX`?

Comment: It says "conversion to `uint16_t` from **`int`** may alter its value", so I believe both values are promoted to `int` before multiplication?

Comment: of course, because you're on a 32bit platform. **Any** `uint16_t` value will fit in an `int`. This wouldn't be the case on 16bit platforms...

Comment: I was referring to the `((int)0xFFFF + 1) * (int)0xFFFF` case, both values fit into `int`, the product is UB, and is then casted back to `uint16_t`, which on 16-bit platforms doesn't happen because everything stays `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Lou ok, if you have **this** as a possible pair of values, you need more casts for "safe" code. I assumed you can assure that your result never overflows.